# Finding the elasticity of function with respect to a variable

Tags: analysis

I am a bit confused as to how to calculate elasticity of a function with respect to a variable. Lets say we have the following function:

$$y^* =\beta^{\frac{1}{1-a}}(\frac{s}{n+\delta})^{\frac{a}{1-a}} \leftrightarrow$$
$$ln y^* = \frac{1}{1-a} * ln (\beta) + \frac{a}{1-a}*ln(s) - \frac{a}{1-a}*ln(n+\delta)$$

How does one see from here what the elasticity of y with respect to $ n + \delta $ is?

Kind regards

Edit:

Elasticity is defined as "In economics, elasticity measures the percentage change of one economic variable in response to a change in another" via Wikipedia. To find the elasticity of y with respect to $n+\delta$, you can use the following formula:

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial (n+\delta)} * \frac{n+\delta}{y} = -\frac{a}{1-a}
$$

But my books suggests I should be able to spot this from the $lny*$ equation. Anyone got any idea how?

Comment: How do you define elasticity?

Comment: Thanks Jose, I have added this to the post.

Comment: You have also wrong the argument of the second logarithm...

Comment: The description of the symbols do not matter. I am just wondering how you can see the elasticity of a function by taking the logarithm of it.

Comment: I have fixed the second logarithm now. Why are you so unkind in your comments?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer now by asking on Econ Stack Exchange.  Factor $\ln y*$ in the following way:
$$\ln y^*\:\:=\:\:\frac{1}{1-a} *\ln(\beta) +\frac{a}{1-a}*\ln(s) -\frac{a}{1-a}*\ln(n+\delta)$$

from which you can see that since $-\frac{a}{1-a}$ is multiplied by $\ln(n+\delta)$, that is the elasticity of $y$ with respect to $n+\delta$.

I refer to [this post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/49998) for deeper explanation.